# Bootstrap 3 Label + Button group inside media div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've this code:

```
<div class="media">
  <i class="icon-graduation-cap pull-left hidden-xs" style="font-size: 40px;padding-top: 20px;"></i>
  <div class="media-body" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <h4 class="title" style="vertical-align: middle">
      <div><a data-toggle="modal" href="/prenotazione/{{$prenotazione->id}}" data-target="#infomodal">title</a>
      </div>
    </h4>
    <p class="summary">LoremIPsum
      <br>
      <span class="label label-info tag"><i class="icon-euro"></i> 2000
       </span>
      <span class="label label-success tag"><i class="icon-trophy"></i> 500</span>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Invoices <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li style="padding: 5px;"><i class="icon-doc"></i> Invoice-name.pdf</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is display something like:

```
Title
Desc lorem ipsum
(label)(label)(button+caret)
```

but I have something like:

```
Title
Desc lorem ipsum
(label)(label)

(button+caret)
```

and the dropdown menù are cropped by .media{overflow: hidden;}

I ask an help to resolve this two issues.

This is a working fiddle:

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/iotivedo/4r2oupbh/)

Comment: make your `.btn-group` inline or inline-block.  But also fix your html - you are not allowed divs inside a p

Comment: you also need to remove overflow hidden from media body for your second error: https://jsfiddle.net/4r2oupbh/11/

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code in snippet. I have used CSS Flex model to align the blocks as per you requirement

> (label)(label)(button+caret)

```css
        .tag {
          font-family: arial;
          padding-top: 4px !important;
          padding-right: 12px !important;
        }

        .media {
          overflow: visible !important;
        }
        
        .flex-container{
          display:flex;
        }
        
        .flex-container > div {
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <i class="icon-graduation-cap pull-left hidden-xs" style="font-size: 40px;padding-top: 20px;"></i>
  <div class="media-body" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <h4 class="title" style="vertical-align: middle">
      <div><a data-toggle="modal" href="/prenotazione/{{$prenotazione->id}}" data-target="#infomodal">title</a>
      </div>
    </h4>
    <section class="summary">LoremIPsum
      <br>
      <div class="flex-container">
      
      <div class="label label-info tag"><i class="icon-euro"></i> 2000
       </div>
      <div class="label label-success tag"><i class="icon-trophy"></i> 500</div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Invoices <span class="caret"></span></button>
      </div>
    
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```